# React: css Scoping using classSet()

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using a flag to set css classes to true/false, when form fields are incorrectly filled. I would like to display the warning message only for the field which has been incorrectly filled. If I use className={warningInputClass}, both the fields will show warning message.

```
var cx = React.addons.classSet;
var warningInputClass = cx({
    'display-warning-message': !this.props.blotterData.isValidFlag,
     'hide-warning-message': this.props.blotterData.isValidFlag
});
```

Question: Is there a way I can scope the classes using classSet() of React?

[image]

Comment: use bind: `var cx = React.addons.classSet.bind(React.addons);`

Comment: you should pass different `blotterData.isValidFlag` as `props` for the two distinct component.

Comment: @nilgun Thanks.I was thinking like if we have better solution without creating extra flags. Looks like in this case, we have to create separate flags.

Comment: @dandavis: I am not exactly sure how do I apply that.